# How to parse multi-level XML in Kenitco

Tags: xml, hierarchical-data, kentico

I have a web service that's passing and XML file to my Kentico site. The file looks something like this:

```
<section_array>
    <section section_title="Section 1">
        <user>
            <first_name>John</first_name>
            <last_name>Doe</last_name>
            <title/>
            <office_number>123 456 7890</office_number>
            <cell_number/>
            <email>john.doe@example.com</email>
            <bio/>
            <photo_url/>
        </user>
        <user>
            <first_name>Johnny</first_name>
            <last_name>Appleseed</last_name>
            <title/>
            <office_number/>
            <cell_number/>
            <email>johnny.appleseed@iliterallyloveapples.com</email>
            <bio/>
            <photo_url/>
        </user>
    </section>
    <section section_title="Section 2">
        <user>
            <first_name>Bob</first_name>
            <last_name>Builder</last_name>
            <title/>
            <office_number>321 654 0987</office_number>
            <cell_number/>
            <email>bobdabuilder@yeswecan.com</email>
            <bio/>
            <photo_url/>
        </user>
    </section>
</section_array>
```

The problem I'm having is this: I can't find a way to get Kentico to recognize any `user` inside the `section`. I am currently using an XML Data Source to pull the data, but it seems that this can't handle more than one level of hierarchy... Is there some way to pull the XML directly into a Universal Viewer or Repeater?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

May i recommend my Universal API viewer?

https://devnet.kentico.com/marketplace/utilities/universal-api-viewer-(with-hierarchy-support)

I'll be updating it shortly to versions 9+, but this has the code to help you create your XML data source and use the transformation engine on it, with hierarchy/multi level support.

Comment: I tried using your web part, but I am unable to get past an "Error loading the WebPart 'UniversalApiViewer' of type 'UniversalApiViewer'" error on the page...

Comment: You probably need the updated code (i just submitted last night the versions 9-11 for the tool, if you need it earlier contact me), OR when you imported you didn't check to include both Files and Global Files, part of the code is in the Global Files.